# How to get Joomla article association?

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, articles, custom-component, multilingual

How can I get the associated articles programmatically in my custom component function?

I have my custom component and I am creating a new article for a multilingual site, so I need to associate articles of different languages.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `JLanguageAssociations::getAssociations`. This function will return an array containing associated items. You can also check if the language filter Items Associations parameter is enabled using `JLanguageAssociations::isEnabled()`.

Here's an example from ROOT/administrator/components/com_content/models/article.php:

```
// Load associated content items
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$assoc = JLanguageAssociations::isEnabled();

if ($assoc)
{
    $item->associations = array();

    if ($item->id != null)
    {
        $associations = JLanguageAssociations::getAssociations('com_content', '#__content', 'com_content.item', $item->id);

        foreach ($associations as $tag => $association)
        {
            $item->associations[$tag] = $association->id;
        }
    }
}

return $item;
```